# xamarin form: binding object is null

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, binding

From the xaml below extracted from a ListView - DataTemplate under ChildInfoIconsView I passing the {Binding .} into the Child property.

I would expect the Child attribute would have the item passed into it, but the Child was null. Is this the way to pass the value of an item to the custom control.

*

```
        <controls:CircleImage 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Style="{StaticResource profileImageStyle}" 
            Source="{Binding Source}" 
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"> 
        </controls:CircleImage>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
           Grid.Row="0" 
           Grid.Column="1"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Start">                              
            <Label AutomationId="aChildName" Style="{StaticResource MediumBoldFont}" x:Name="childName" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
            <local:ChildInfoIconsView 
                Child="{Binding .}"
                VerticalOptions="Fill">
            </local:ChildInfoIconsView> 
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</local:ExtendedFrame>
```

Code :

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty ChildProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Child), typeof(ChildModel), typeof(ChildModel), null, BindingMode.OneWay, null);

    public ChildModel Child
            {
                get
                {
                    var a = (ChildModel)GetValue(ChildProperty);
                    //a is null.
                    return (ChildModel)GetValue(ChildProperty);
                }
                set
                {
                    SetValue(ChildProperty, value);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You probably should just use `{Binding}`, get rid of the `.`

Comment: I added the  propertyChanging: (BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue) in the ChildProperty section. I can see the newValue does have an object inside.