# BindableProperty setter is never called

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a binding in my `ListView`'s ItemTemplate,

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Capsules}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <views:CapsuleWidgetView Model="{Binding}"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And in my CapsuleWidgetView component, I have

```
public CapsuleWidgetViewModel ViewModel => (CapsuleWidgetViewModel)BindingContext;

public CapsuleModel Model
{
    get => (CapsuleModel)GetValue(ModelProperty);
    set => SetValue(ModelProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty ModelProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Model),
    typeof(CapsuleModel),
    typeof(CapsuleWidgetView),
    propertyChanged: (bindable, value, newValue) =>
    {
        var view = (CapsuleWidgetView)bindable;
        var modelValue = (CapsuleModel)newValue;

        view.ViewModel.Capsule = modelValue;
    });
```

Whenever the bound collection for my `ListView` changes, the items are regenerated as expected. However, each `Model` is always null, and the property setter is never called. Not from the `ModelProperty` propertyChanged, nor my defined setter method. I've confirmed this with the debugger and attempted logging.

I originally thought my problem was from the [binding being null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53717473/), but this doesn't seem to be the case. Another test where I access the bound object's properties succeeds. Even then, the source collection will never have a null object added to it.

*However*, a `CapsuleModel` directly defined in Xaml works A-OK.

```
<views:CapsuleWidgetView>
    <views:CapsuleWidgetView.Model>
        <models:CapsuleModel Name="Hello?"/>
    </views:CapsuleWidgetView.Model>
</views:CapsuleWidgetView>
```

Referencing the properties of the model and binding them to something like `Label.Text` works, I'm sure the problem stems from my `BindableProperty` and/or `BindingContext`. Nothing seems wrong with either, though.

Comment: Is the item in the Capsules a observable object?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT By item do you mean the collection? If so, yes. If you mean the CapsuleModel, no, and it shouldn't need to be afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39989721/16324801),

> Never do `BindingContext = this;` in your ContentView, as it hijacks the context from the Page trying to databind to it. Instead use `Content.BindingContext = this;`

In my case, the `BindingContext` was being set in Xaml, which would be equivalent to `BindingContext = this;`. I simply removed it and added it to my constructor like so,

```
public CapsuleWidgetView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
        
    Content.BindingContext = new CapsuleWidgetViewModel();
}
```

Note that it can't be placed above `InitializeComponent` because the `Content` hasn't actually been created yet.

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't the `<views:CapsuleWidgetView Model="{Binding}"/>` have a binding property name such as `<views:CapsuleWidgetView Model="{Binding Model}"/>`?

In the viewmodel:

```
[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<Capsule> Capsules;
```

And in the model:

```
public class Capsule : ObservableObject
{
  private CapsuleModel model;
  public CapsuleModel Model
  {
   get => model;
   set => SetProperty(ref model, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to bind to the data template's binding context. There is no Model property, the Capsules *are* my models, hence "self".

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand clearly. Can you tell me what do you want to bind the `<views:CapsuleWidgetView Model="{Binding}"/>` to directly? @zeplar_exe

Comment: Each `CapsuleWidgetView`  has its `Model` property which is of type `CapsuleModel`. As such, I need to create one for every model in `Capsules`, which is an `ObservableCollection<CapsuleModel>`.

Comment: All right, I have understood. You want to bind each item in the `Capsules` to the `CapsuleWidgetView`'s model property, not the `CapsuleWidgetView`. Right? @zeplar_exe

Comment: Correct, that's what I'm aiming for.

Comment: But that's impossible, the item in the `Capsules` is the data source of the each `CapsuleWidgetView`. You can just use another model to contain the `CapsuleModel` and set the `ObservableCollection<AnotherModel>` as the itemsource. @zeplar_exe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247663/discussion-between-zeplar-exe-and-liyun-zhang-msft).